# PHP PDO - alternative for mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

With mysqli I can get the number of rows from a select query by using mysqli_num_rows. I can't find a way to do that with PDO without having to do a separate query like `SELECT COUNT(*)`? I don't see the point in doing a separate query when I already have a recordset.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: That counts affected rows. This is one of the reasons why I recommend, if you are only using MySQL, you don't bother my PDO and use mysqli instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows). For example:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, name FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100"); 
$result->execute();
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"); 
$result->execute();
$row_count =$result->fetchColumn();
echo $row_count;
```

This option is normally used to get full match counts when you have a `LIMIT` clause, however, it works just fine without one, and it's much more efficient than issuing the same query again with a `COUNT(*)` since it just retrieves the count value stored by the first query value and does not have to run another full query.

Comment: I found a way to do it by counting the result set `count($result->fetchAll())`. Not sure if this is faster than FOUND_ROWS?

Answer (score 4):

In Pdo you use `rowCount`. Example: `$string-> rowCount ();`

Comment: What kind of object is `$string` ?

Comment: From php.net : For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

Comment: @u_mulder well, is there an alternative?

Comment: `rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement. It does not work for select.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM `table` WHERE condition"; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 

$result->execute();
$row_count =$result->fetchColumn();
echo $row_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

> For most databases, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` **does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.** Instead, use
>   PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {

  /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        /*    .... */
```

I don't want to copy the whole PHP.net page, please just read it.

**Why does PDO not have `num_rows` ?**

You may think it's slower to have 2 queries but it isn't. PDO is a general client library for several database systems, not only MySQL. For performance reasons, not everys database system has internal, technical ability to calculate the total rows in select uppon the query. Knowing the total number of rows requires to examine all rows before serving them.

Comment: I would add an `F` to `RTM` :)

Comment: No swearing on SO for me, but yea :D RTFM makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: I read that but why do I have to do a separate query when I already have a recordset? From my op "I can't find a way to do that with PDO without having to do a separate query like SELECT COUNT(*)"

Comment: "Returns the number of rows **affected** by the last SQL statement" There are no rows affected within a `SELECT`.

Comment: @sol I added an explanation (without reference).

Comment: It might not be slower but it's still more code. I found a way to do it by counting the result set `count($result->fetchAll())`. I'm not sure which way has better performance?

Comment: @sol more code isn't bad. Fetching the **whole** resultset at once and counting the results is bad.